# Select column on Kendo grid not working on extended widget

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have created an extended version of the Kendo grid.

```
var base = kendo.ui.Grid;

var CustomGrid = base.extend({
    init: function (element, options) {
        var that = this;            
        base.fn.init.call(that, element, options);
    },
    options: {
        name: "CustomGrid"
    }
```

The Grid is being extended rather than being encapsulated into a component. The control was made quite late during the development process and, among other things, this introduced the least amount of rework on our code.

On this grid, I want a Select columnn, which Kendo natively supports [as of the Kendo UI R2 2017 SP1 release](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.selectable). My problem is that, while the checkboxes get rendered correctly on the grid, (un)checking them does not (un)select the rows. My guess is that the underlying functionality searches for objects with certain attribute values which are different on my custom widget. For example, the Kendo grid will have `data-role='grid'`, whereas mine has `data-role='customgrid'`.

I have tried creating my own select column, using the [Telerik documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-selection-checkbox) as a guide. While this works, it only handles the basics. It becomes more complicated when you add in sorting, filtering, etc.

What would I need to do to get the inbuilt select column working for the extended Kendo grid?

Comment: Why are you extending the grid? What we did do in our project, was a) doing a component with a grid inside, b) helper functions to generate complex gird options, and c) a custom selection manager, since Kendo's select checkboxes are incompatible with many things like keyboard navigation. Yes, it's a lot.

Comment: @GaloisGirl I updated my question.

Comment: I think it's based on the CSS class k-state-selected, per https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.selectable.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My work does have a license, and I asked the question of Telerik support as well. They replied yesterday and their answer seems to be working well! Paraphrased below:

> Internally we have a condition which checks whether the currently selected row belongs to the current grid to avoid selecting rows of parent grids in the context of hierarchical grids.
>   However, the getKendoGrid will not return the instance of the widget when the grid is custom. As a workaround I can suggest you to override the _checkboxClick and _headerCheckboxClick functions of the grid.

```
kendo.ui.Grid.fn._checkboxClick = function (e) {
    var that = this,
        row = $(e.target).closest("tr"),
        isSelecting = !row.hasClass('k-state-selected');

    if (!that.dataSource.getByUid(row.attr('data-uid'))) {
        return;
    }

    if (isSelecting) {
        that.select(row);
    } else {
        that._deselectCheckRows(row);
    }
}

kendo.ui.Grid.fn._headerCheckboxClick = function (e) {
    var that = this,
        checkBox = $(e.target),
        checked = checkBox.prop("checked");

    if (!that.thead.find(checkBox).length) {
        return;
    }

    if (checked) {
        that.select(that.items());
    } else {
        that.clearSelection();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Kendo license, download the source code and check out the private grid method _persistSelectedRows. They track ids. Here's where it gets tricky: newly added items (not yet persisted in the database) may not have an id. If you assign them ids, then the dataSource won't see them as new items to save. If you don't, you can't persist their selection. You can persist uids instead, but if you refresh the grid, the uids will be re-generated and your selection will be lost.

We ended up writing a custom selection manager based on uids, but that's proprietary code I'm not at liberty to share.

Since the grid implies you do have a license, I suggest you take advantage of Kendo's support.